# force inno setup to store data in HKCU with PrivilegesRequired=lower

Tags: inno-setup

When Inno Setup configured with PrivilegesRequired=admin, it stores uninstall registry key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

How can i force to store uninstall registry key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

Comment: +1, good question; but just one question, are you sure you need administrator privileges for each user running your setup ? Don't forget that all those users have to know the administrator credentials to install/uninstall your application and that they might share the same folders or sessions.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? you could use `CreateUninstallRegKey=no` and create the Uninstall key in HKCU manually in the Registry section.

Comment: I'am migrating from NSIS installer to Inno Setup. For first version i need administrative previleges to remove old installation and manage some stuff. Currently i've solved this runnig all legacy support commands with ShellExec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your title said, you need to use `PrivilegesRequired=lowest`. Anything other than that, and the "local user" may not be what you expect.

If the setup needs admin permissions to remove the old setup, you can use `ShellExec`, making sure that the application you're calling as the admin manifest, or you pass the "runas" verb.